# Proxmox marked as down on monitoring platform

Tags: nfs, snmp, proxmox, synology, network-storage

I have 3 Proxmoxs (ve 4.1) setup in a Cluster.

They had an NFS storage attached to them (synology cluster) with an active and a passive node.

I decided to cut them out of the proxmox just after i have free them of any VM or backups,...

Everything is working fine but at this point, something weird appended.

My 3 Proxmoxs was marked as down on my monitoring platform (Observium)(SNMP)
No additional information in the log, just "device changed state to down".

I have not shut them down yet(synology), disabling the NFS sharing was enough to produce that issue.

I have disabled that NFS storage and deleted it on the proxmox.
they don't use it anymore.

But as i said, cutting NFS sharing on the synology mark the proxmoxs as down in my monitoring platform.

But Proxmoxs are working fine.

I did not find something useful on google to help me with that problem

So i am asking you your help =)

If you got some ideas or if you have already experienced this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out:

i just added

```
skipNFSInHostResources true
```

into /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

then i did service snmpd restart.

And that's it. I think snmpd do not care anymore about NFS storage that have been linked to the server.

As effect, my devices came back on my monitoring platform.